# Nuxtjs fails to load some modern.js files in UK

Tags: google-cloud-platform, caching, nuxt.js

I'm facing a very strange issue with nuxt 2.15.8 during production and specifically users who opens the site from UK. The main issue is that images are not hydrating, so after investigation the only thing I could notice in the console is this error

```
GET https://my-site-name.com/_nuxt/a5d3b1c.modern.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404
```

There are like 4 or 5 similar errors to this one. I can't ever replicate the issue locally and It never happens unless the user is opening the site from UK. I can replicate it in production by turning on a VPN in UK and open the site in incognito mode.

Any ideas that might fix the issue? The site is deployed on `GoogleCloud` and `cloudflare`.

Comment: I'd suggest disabling Cloudflare's proxy and checking again. Cloudflare might be serving up cached static assets from a previous build- if so, you can handle this as part of your deployment. Also, is the site load balanced?

Comment: The thing is that I have many sites running on Cloudflare and they are all having the same config and none of them is facing this issue. The cache is always purged with each new deployment.

Comment: Regardless, did you switch it off for this site and test again, to rule Cloudflare out as a potential cause? If the issues persists without Cloudflare in the middle, we know the issue lies elsewhere.

Comment: Turned out to be a caching issue from Cloudflare's side.